How to use bash for loop to awk print FPAT string found in quoted variable
I cant figure out the proper FPAT to get each comma separated value. Using bash on Debian 12.5... I have a file PING.cfg with contents:
NODE01="router,10.0.0.1,5"
NODE02="dns1,68.6.16.30,35"
NODE03="dns2,1.1.1.1,35"

Those get used as variables sourced in multiple scripts, I want a script to assign each of the comma separated values to a variable in a for loop, maybe something like this:
for n in `grep NODE PING.cfg`
        do
        NODENAME=$(echo "$n" | awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' -F',' '{ print $1 }')
        HOSTIP=$(echo "$n" | awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' -F',' '{ print $2 }')
        echo "NODE is $NODENAME and HOSTIP is $HOSTIP"
done

But awk does not seem to be reading inside the quotes with my FPAT pattern, the output for $1 includes the entire variable:
NODE is NODE01="router and HOSTIP is 10.0.0.1

Tried FPAT to specify quotes.

It doesn't make sense to use both FPAT and -F. FPAT overrides -F.

Are you sure you're using GNU awk? I FPAT is a GNU extension.

How do you expect your code to work with FPAT, though? The pattern matches the entire "dns1,68.6.16.30,35" portion of the line. There's only one of these on each line, so how do you expect $1 and $2 to separate the host and IP?

It seems like you actually want is to extract the part of the line between quotes, then use split() to split that at commas.

GNU Awk 3.1.5 and hopefully mawk 1.3.4

Those are both literally about 20 years out of date and neither will support FPAT (introduced in gawk 4.0). Can you update your GNU awk version? We're currently on version 5.3.0 which has a lot of new functionality and bug fixes.

@Allan Wind the file has some other random content besides what is shown which I want to ignore in the variables I bring in. Not sure how to mix that in reading the whole file.

If your real input has random content you want to ignore then make sure to include such random content in your sample input so you don't end up with a solution to the wrong problem.

Perhaps instead update this configuration file to use a format which is simple and natural to use from Bash and Awk. Fixing those other scripts which already use this file is a one-time job and will possibly simplify them as well.

I have never seen grep enveloped in GRAVE ACCENTS, though I am certainly not grep-ninja, so please explain why you elected to do so.

Assuming you need these values inside a shell loop for some reason, this might be what you want, using any awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r nodename hostip rest; do
    printf 'nodename is %s and hostip is %s\n' "$nodename" "$hostip"
done < <(awk -F'[",]' '/^NODE/{print $2, $3}' PING.cfg)


$ ./tst.sh
nodename is router and hostip is 10.0.0.1
nodename is dns1 and hostip is 68.6.16.30
nodename is dns2 and hostip is 1.1.1.1

I'm using lower case variable names for the reasons described at Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization.

Thanks Ed, that is a very clear example and does exactly what I need.

As bash is tagged, you can also use regular expressions with capture groups, which can be accessed via the ${BASH_REMATCH[@]} array. A well-composed regex can even be used to only consider lines containing NODE, replacing your initial grep filter:
while read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^(NODE[0-9]+)=\"([0-9a-z]+),([0-9.]+),([0-9]+)\"$ ]] &&
  # BASH_REMATCH ╰────[1]───╯   ╰───[2]───╯ ╰──[3]──╯ ╰──[4]─╯
  echo "NODE is ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} and HOSTIP is ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done < PING.cfg

NODE is router and HOSTIP is 10.0.0.1
NODE is dns1 and HOSTIP is 68.6.16.30
NODE is dns2 and HOSTIP is 1.1.1.1


I don't think you're using a version of awk that supports FPAT. But even if it did, it wouldn't do what you seem to expect.
Instead, start by using quotes as the field separators. Then the string dns1,68.6.16.30,35 will be field 2. You can then use split() to split this at comma delimiters.
NODENAME=$(echo "$n" | awk -F'"' '{ split($2, a, /,/); print a[1] }')
HOSTIP=$(echo "$n" | awk -F'"' '{ split($2, a, /,/); print a[2] }')

This solution doesn't require any GNU extensions, these are all POSIX features.

Portability is preferred, so your point on the awk version is noted. I am open to re-formatting the file, but it is a multi-purpose file that I also need to source in to other scripts to use those as variables, so quoting each individual field would mess that up. My goal is to be able to grab dns1 as a single variable, and the IP address as another variable.

I never said anything that suggests reformatting the file.

I've updated the answer to show how to assign the shell variables in your script using my technique, instead of doing the entire loop in awk.


Those get used as variables sourced in multiple scripts

If the file is already sourced (or sourcing them won't be an issue), you can access the variables starting with NODE using the Bash parameter expansion ${!prefix@}:
. PING.cfg

for n in "${!NODE@}"; do readarray -td, vals <<< "${!n}"
  echo "NODE is ${vals[0]} and HOSTIP is ${vals[1]}"
done

# or

for n in "${!NODE@}"; do IFS=, read -r node hostip value <<< "${!n}"
  echo "NODE is $node and HOSTIP is $hostip"
done

# or

for n in "${!NODE@}"; do printf "NODE is %s and HOSTIP is %s\n" \
  "$(cut -d, -f1 <<< "${!n}")" "$(cut -d, -f2 <<< "${!n}")"
done

NODE is router and HOSTIP is 10.0.0.1
NODE is dns1 and HOSTIP is 68.6.16.30
NODE is dns2 and HOSTIP is 1.1.1.1


You file has "-sheared values and 2nd field has ,-sheared values, therefore I suggest using cut twice. Let PING.cfg content be
NODE01="router,10.0.0.1,5"
NODE02="dns1,68.6.16.30,35"
NODE03="dns2,1.1.1.1,35"

then
for n in `grep NODE PING.cfg`
        do
        NODENAME=$(echo "$n" | cut -d '"' -f 2 | cut -d ',' -f 1)
        HOSTIP=$(echo "$n" | cut -d '"' -f 2 | cut -d ',' -f 2)
        echo "NODE is $NODENAME and HOSTIP is $HOSTIP"
done

gives following output
NODE is router and HOSTIP is 10.0.0.1
NODE is dns1 and HOSTIP is 68.6.16.30
NODE is dns2 and HOSTIP is 1.1.1.1

Observe that it will give same results as using GNU AWK with [",] field separator (FS) and retrieving 2nd and 3rd field respectively if and only if there is never " before = and there is never , before =, therefore if you can provide that always hold true I suggest using more verbose cut-cut approach.

something like ..., my two bits ..
awk -V
GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.

# using poster's supplied input ...
awk -F'"' '{split($2,bits,","); print "NODE is " bits[1] " and HOSTIP is " bits[2]}' < PING.cfg 
NODE is router and HOSTIP is 10.0.0.1
NODE is dns1 and HOSTIP is 68.6.16.30
NODE is dns2 and HOSTIP is 1.1.1.1

